# What's the possible cause of this Core Data crash

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

First of all, I'm sorry I can't figure out a better title for this question.

This is a crash that I can not repeat myself but happened to users many times. I'm using HockeyApp([QuincyKit](https://github.com/TheRealKerni/QuincyKit/)) to collect crash reports. So I can't debug this problem, I can only read the call stack. But I don't have a clue of what's wrong after reading it. I omitted several irrelevant function calls in the middle.

For the UI part, I'm using `NSFetchedResultsController` to populate `UITableView`.

For the Core Data part, I'm using iOS 5's newly introduced parent-child MOCs: parent MOC for the main queue, child MOC for the resource fetching queue. I save child MOC after processing fetched data in it. As soon as I save child MOC, the changes should be pushed into parent MOC automatically by Core Data and FRC should be see the changes and update table view via its delegate. I then call back into the main thread to do extra UI update.

Specifically, I can understand how `[UITableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:]` called into `[NSFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:]`, but I can't see why it finally called into my entity's `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` and why `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` would cause unfulfilled fault. I think `[NSFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:]` should do `fetch`, but it did `insert` here.

```
Exception Type:  SIGABRT
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x35e7e32c
Crashed Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSObjectInaccessibleException', reason: 'CoreData could not fulfill a fault for '0xe62bdc0 <x-coredata://327F5799-CAB1-4086-8E75-0E87F0E19BF0/Status/p385>''

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x355c888f __exceptionPreprocess + 162
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3796f259 objc_exception_throw + 32
2   CoreData                            0x35f124f3 _PFFaultHandlerLookupRow + 1098
3   CoreData                            0x35f11d5b _PF_FulfillDeferredFault + 194
4   CoreData                            0x35f11c0b _sharedIMPL_pvfk_core + 38    
5   XXX                                0x0008a5c3 -[Tweet initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:] (Tweet.m:125)
6   XXX                                0x0003fd1b -[Status initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:] (Status.m:333)
7   CoreData                            0x35f0eded -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _initWithEntity:withID:withHandler:withContext:] + 164
8   CoreData                            0x35f0de07 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _retainedObjectWithID:optionalHandler:withInlineStorage:] + 134
9   CoreData                            0x35f6b6eb _PFRetainedObjectIDCore + 330
10  CoreData                            0x35f67065 -[NSManagedObjectContext objectWithID:] + 88
11  CoreData                            0x35f32c09 _faultBatchAtIndex + 1352
12  CoreData                            0x35f31e73 -[_PFBatchFaultingArray objectAtIndex:] + 42
13  CoreData                            0x35f30a87 -[_PFMutableProxyArray objectAtIndex:] + 82
14  CoreData                            0x35fdd81d -[NSFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:] + 204
16  XXX                                0x0009ebab -[TweetsViewController tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:] (TweetsViewController.m:581)
17  UIKit                               0x3304dab5 -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 2548
18  UIKit                               0x33067c3b -[UITableViewRowData rectForSection:] + 302
19  UIKit                               0x33125981 -[UITableViewRowData indexPathsForRowsInRect:] + 136
20  UIKit                               0x331258f1 -[UITableView indexPathsForRowsInRect:] + 52
21  UIKit                               0x33125889 -[UITableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:] + 28
22  XXX                                0x0009c193 -[TweetsViewController updateUI] (TweetsViewController.m:211)
25  XXX                                0x00111a6f __block_global_1 (ResourceFetcher.m:68)
26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x34458b87 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke + 82
27  libdispatch.dylib                   0x34457ee7 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 194
28  CoreFoundation                      0x3559b2ad __CFRunLoopRun + 1268
29  CoreFoundation                      0x3551e4a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
30  CoreFoundation                      0x3551e36d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
31  GraphicsServices                    0x371ba439 GSEventRunModal + 136
32  UIKit                               0x3302acd5 UIApplicationMain + 1080
33  XXX                                0x000044ff main (main.m:16)
34  XXX                                0x00003c50 start + 40
```

Users with this crash problems usually see the table view turns from full-of-cells into empty suddenly immediate before the crash. I think it is am important hint but I can't think of any reasons why all the data is gone suddenly — I don't have code to move or delete the database file.

Comment: Most likely cause is that you have an array of fetched objects that was about to be used to populate a tableview and your store has changed in the background (i.e. you downloaded and replaced it with new data, copy a new database file over the old one etc. The other possibility is that you are using the same `managedobjectcontext` in different threads.

Comment: @Rog As I said in the question, I'm using `NSFetchedResultsController` to populate my `UITableView`. I'm using MOC in multi-threads with iOS 5's parent-child pattern, and all my data are finally saved in the main MOC, so I think my data are in good sync. FYI, the backtrace in the question is for the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I think I've fixed the crash though I'm not sure whether it is my bug or Core Data's bug.

First of all, it has nothing to do with the sync among MOCs.

Secondly, yes, `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` is called when objects are first instantiated in moc, whether they are newly created or fetched with a request. So it seem the doc is misleading:

> If context is not nil, this method invokes [context insertObject:self]
>   (which causes awakeFromInsert to be invoked).

If it is called for fetching, `awakeFromFetch` is invoked.

As you can see in the backtrace, the crash happened in my overridden `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`. Reasonable enough, `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` turned out to be the cause of the crash. But I don't think I did anything bad in it. I just used some persistent attributes to initialize some non-persistent attributes:

```
- (id)initWithEntity:(NSEntityDescription *)entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {
    self = [super initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
    if (self) {
        // xxx_ is a persistent attribute while _xxx is the corresponding non-persistent attribute as its cache in memory only to reduce reading cost.
        _xxx = self.xxx_.unsignedIntegerValue;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Sometimes when I read the first persistent attribute the unfulfillable exception was thrown up.

I always know that

> You are discouraged from overriding this method—you should instead
>   override awakeFromInsert and/or awakeFromFetch (if there is logic
>   common to these methods, it should be factored into a third method
>   which is invoked from both). If you do perform custom initialization
>   in this method, you may cause problems with undo and redo operations.

But I don't know it would cause unfulfillable exceptions. Is it a Core Data bug? Otherwise, what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3):

First off, when looking for bugs, there are no irrelevant function calls, so you should probably edit with the entire call stack...

It looks like you are requesting an object (see the objectWithID call), but when the managed object context goes to get it, it can not find it.

This usually happens when you have a separate thread that is deleting objects, and you are not managing the changes properly.

So, do you have any other threads that are changing the state of your core data store?  If so, that's probably your culprit.

Core Data isn't that hard... but it does have several rules that if you do not follow, you will be in trouble.

First, make sure you do not access a MOC from multiple threads.

Second, if multiple threads are changing the underlying store, make sure you properly synchronize with all MOCS - either using parent/child contexts or watching the DidSave notifications.

**EDIT**

You commented:

> Yes, I'm also suspecting there are some deleting-something-in-use
>   problems. But first of all, do you know why
>   initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext: is called here?

Yes... it needs to instantiate the object.  Look at your call stack, and you can see it...

Your UI is trying to update on the main thread...

```
22  XXX  0x0009c193 -[TweetsViewController updateUI] (TweetsViewController.m:211)
```

Accordingly, the UIKit does its thing, and makes a delegate callback to your controller...

```
16  XXX  0x0009ebab -[TweetsViewController tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:] (TweetsViewController.m:581)
```

Which causes the FRC call that you are talking about...

```
14  CoreData  0x35fdd81d -[NSFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:] + 204
```

And then, the object is needed, so it is fetched...

```
10  CoreData  0x35f67065 -[NSManagedObjectContext objectWithID:] + 88
```

Well, even Core Data has to instantiate the object.  It does not have some magic interface.  It calls the normal API for creating a managed object...  obviously you are requesting an object of type "Status"

```
6   XXX  0x0003fd1b -[Status initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:] (Status.m:333)
```

This object, in turn, needs an object of type "Tweet"...

```
5   XXX  0x0008a5c3 -[Tweet initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:] (Tweet.m:125)
```

And then, when it has to instantiate that object... which fails because it can't find it.  So, again, my bet is that you have a logic error in your synchronization.  Either you are deleting an object and not properly notifying other contexts, so they are still referencing a deleted object...  or you are referring to an object that was not really saved... or you have changed a relationship, but not properly notified other contexts.

Either way, I think it is a good bet that if you track down how you change the database, you are violating some standard protocol for updating in multiple threads.

In fact, you can even see how you are getting there...

updateUI is being called from a a GCD dispatch queue.  Most likely, in ResourceFetcher, you are making a call into the main thread.  In that code, make sure you have properly saved your context and made all notifications before you ask the main thread to update itself.

You'd be better off listening to DidSave events from the other MOC, then after updating from that context, calling your UI to update itself.

Comment: I'm sure those omitted functions are irrelevant for discussion here because they are all consecutive functions defined in my app. I only kept the deepest one here. I think it is OK and more clear, isn't it? I'm using MOC in multi-threads with iOS 5's parent-child pattern, and all my data are finally saved in the main MOC, so I think my data are in good sync. FYI, the backtrace in the question is for the main thread.

Comment: Yep.  Without more information, I'd bet that's your problem.  You are not properly managing the changes to the storage.  One thread is changing the underlying store (most likely a delete), and the other is expecting it to be there and not finding it.  The other best bet is that you may be accessing objects from the wrong thread/MOC combo.

Comment: Yes, I'm also suspecting there are some deleting-something-in-use problems. But first of all, do you know why `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` is called here?

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. However, doesn't `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` create a new object which would be saved as a new record into database later? I asked why it was called because I thought here FRC was asking for an existing object to populate the table view, not creating a new object.

Comment: I'm using parent-child MOCs: parent MOC for the main queue, child MOC for the resource fetching queue. I save child MOC after processing fetched data in it. As soon as I save child MOC, the changes should be pushed into parent MOC automatically by Core Data and FRC should be see the changes and update table view via its delegate. I then call back into the main thread to do extra UI update. I can't see how there can be any MOC sync problems. What did I overlook?

Comment: When saving the child MOC, the changes are pushed to the parent MOC.  But are you saving the parent MOC?  The MOC is just a scratchpad and the changes aren't propagated until the save.  Once u save the parent MOC, the FRC should notice the changes and update the UI.  You should'nt have to refresh the UI yourself.

Comment: Since I don't have all your code, of course I can't tell you exactly what's happening.  But, that exception is very clear.  You are asking Core Data to fulfill a fault for an object that does not exist in the database.  So, either you have deleted the object from the store, or you are some how faulting an object ID that was never created.  Step through your stack trace. Find out which object is being faulted, and why.  Also don't forget about the com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug flag.  Set it to some positive number on the command line to see what is happening at the SQL level.

Comment: BTW, what, exactly, are you doing in that child MOC?